# NHibernate Join Fetch(Kind)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Given a Team -> Athlete relationship and querying all athletes. What
am I misunderstanding about `fetch="Join"`? Should this mapping cause
the Team to be loaded via a join? When iterating the athletes, it
still lazy loads the Team.

```
public class AthleteMap : ClassMapping<Athlete>
{
        public AthleteMap()
        {
            ManyToOne(a => a.Team, o =>
                                       {
                                           o.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                                           o.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                                       }
                );    
        }    
}
```

Which produces this HBM:

```
<class name="Athlete" table="Athletes">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" />
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
    <many-to-one name="Team" fetch="join" lazy="false" />
    <property name="Created" />
</class>
```

iterating:

```
var session = factory.OpenSession();

 foreach (var athlete in session.Query<Athlete>())
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", athlete.FirstName, athlete.Team.Name);
```

Comment: Do you get a exception? Wich?

Comment: So when you iterate you see queries fetching a `Team` per `athlete`? I mean, the mapping is correct, apart from the eager fetch?

Comment: No Exception. @GertArnold yes while iterating, it queries the Team on every iteration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The NHibernate Linq Query doesn't use the fetch strategy of the mapping. You have to Fetch() in your linq query like this.

```
var session = factory.OpenSession();

foreach (var athlete in session.Query<Athlete>().Fetch(x => x.Team))
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", athlete.FirstName, athlete.Team.Name);
```

The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:

- retrieval via Get() or Load()
- retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
- ICriteria queries
- HQL queries if subselect fetching is used

source:[performance-fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-custom)

Comment: Thanks... shame their Linq implementation is incomplete like this.