# How does fetch work

Tags: nhibernate, conform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NHibernate Join Fetch(Kind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232420/nhibernate-join-fetchkind)

I have read article.
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/03/conform-mapping-components.html

Tried to reproduce it on my project and got strange behavioral.

I have two entites:

```
Plan 
{ 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual Payer Payer { get; set; } 
} 

Payer 
{ 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Mapping for it:

```
 orm.Cascade<Payer, Plan >(CascadeOn.Persist | CascadeOn.Merge); 
 orm.Cascade<Plan, Payer>(CascadeOn.None);
```

Fetch:

```
mapper.Customize<CarePlan>(cm => cm.ManyToOne(o => o.Payer, x => 
x.Fetch(FetchKind.Join)));
```

Simple get:

```
    var plan = session.Query<Plan>().Where(c=>c.Id == 
    1).SingleOrDefault(); 

 Console.WriteLine(plan.Payer.Name);
```

And I got this queries:

```
select careplan0_.Id 
       careplan0_.PayerId 
from   CarePlans careplan0_ 
where  careplan0_.Id = 1 /* @p0 */ 
and other query 
SELECT payer0_.Id , 
payer0_.Name    as Name 
FROM   Payers payer0_ 
WHERE  payer0_.Id = 2
```

Why I got 2 queries? How can I get one query with join?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232420/nhibernate-join-fetchkind

Comment: It`s the anwser. How can I set this question as duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

var plan = session.Query()
    .Where(c=>c.Id == 1)
    .Fetch(x => x.Player).Eager
    .SingleOrDefault();

Try disabling lazy load, so it will eager load by default

Comment: This code works good. But I want set it up in the mapping.